# PHP code that skips the if and go straight into the else statement

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, if-statement

For some reason it wont go into my if statement...

It's probably something obvious but its late and I've been stuck here for a half an hour...

```
<?php
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            if ($id == "") {
                //it goes here correctly
            } else {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= $id");
                if ($result == "0") {
                    //It does not go here.
                } else {
                   //It goes here correctly
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Much appreciated.. - Luca

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you expect to get `0` as a return value from `mysql_query`.

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (emphasis mine):

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a **resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error**.
>
> [...]
>
> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement or mysql_affected_rows() to find out how many rows
>   were affected by a DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, or UPDATE statement.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
>   have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

So, by guessing, the code you really want would be:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($id == "") {
    //it goes here correctly
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= $id");
    if ($result === false || mysql_num_rows($result) === 0) {
        //It always goes to else statement.
    } else {
       //It goes here correctly
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. I'm fairly new to PHP. Much appreciated.

Comment: @LucaDeCaprio Glad to help. If you think an answer solved your question, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is ok, then [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a resource, `$result == "0"` is `false` always.

Comment: Ohh gotcha.. I'm very new to PHP. Thank you

Comment: @LucaDeCaprio You're welcome. Remember that you can always use `var_dump` to see what you have for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Even if  you dont have any data for that id, it returns "true", because the your query successfully executed. 
Instead you can try like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= $id");
 $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($rows>0){
  //you have data to work with 
 }
 else{
  //no data 
 }
```